# Protecting VNC server with SSH tunneling without preventing iPhone connection

Tags: vnc

I have a VNC server that I hope to access from multiple computers as well as my phone (using the VNC viewer app). I have a password on the server but that did not stop me from getting "Too many authentication failures" eventually from someone trying to break into my linux box.

I would set up ssh tunneling but I am not sure how I could get that to work such that my phone can still connect to the VNC server. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Setup iptable rules to prevent repeated connection requests like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent  --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 -j DROP
```

This can be adapted to any port and it will prevent brute-force attacks and flooding to some degree. The seconds can be adjusted to make it more effective, the lower the seconds the more it will block. It should help you.

Or you could use a service like fail2ban, this will also help with your issue:

[Fail2ban Website](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)